# I cannot send data to the server and i can't and I also did not receive data from the server

Tags: node.js, react-native

I am learning react-native and I have some problems developing the login function

this is my fetch function in react-native

```
getLogin = () => {
fetch("http://localhost:5000/auth/login", {
  method: 'POST',
  header: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    email: `${this.state.email}`,
    pass: `${this.state.pass}`,
  }),
})
  .then((res) => res.json())
  .then((data) => {
    console.log(this.state)
    console.log(data)
    if (!this.state.success) {
      console.log(data)
      console.log("Login false!");
    }
    else {
      console.log(data);
      console.log("Login success");
    }
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
  });
 }
```

this is my code in server

```
module.exports.postLogin = (req, res) => {
  console.log(req)
  var email = req.body.email
  var pass = req.body.pass
  var user = db.get('users').find({ email: email }).value()

  if (!user) {
  res.json({
   errors: [
     "user does not exist "
    ],
     values: req.body,
   })
 }

 if (user.pass !== pass) {
   res.json({
   errors: [
       "wrong pass "
    ],
    values: req.body,
  })
}

 res.json({
   success: true
 })
 res.cookie("userID", user.id, {
   signed: true
 })  
}
```

I cannot send data to the server and i can't and I also did not receive data from the server
please help me, thanks for sp

Comment: What happens when you log req obj? Is it working?

Comment: Use " if (data.success===null) {} " instead of  "if (!this.state.success) {}"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two solutions :

1. Use the **IP address** of  your machine instead of localhost and make sure that your machine and your device and emulator running in the same network
2. Solution2 : you can use **ngrok** https://ngrok.com/ that is will generate an HTTPS URL for your server code running in the port:5000 and it can be accessed from other devices

Answer (score 0):

If you are running the app on a real device or android emulator, than your problem is that localhost is not pointing to your machine in which your server runs. See [this answer](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/10404#issuecomment-267303151) on an issue.

> The solution is to replace localhost with the IP address of your machine.